# BroadcastBlock missing items

Tags: tpl-dataflow

I have a list of project numbers that I need to process. A project could have about 8000 items and I need to get the data for each item in the project and then push this data into a list of servers. Can anybody please tell me the following..

1) I have 1000 items in iR but only 998 were written to the servers.  Did I loose items by using broadCastBlock? 
2) Am I doing the await on all actionBlocks correctly?
3) How do I make the database call async?

Here is the database code

```
    public  MemcachedDTO GetIR(MemcachedDTO dtoItem)
    {

        string[] Tables = new string[] { "iowa", "la" };
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("test", connection))
            {
                DataSet Result = new DataSet();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@ProjectId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                command.Parameters["@ProjectId"].Value = dtoItem.ProjectId;


                connection.Open();
                Result.EnforceConstraints = false;
                Result.Load(command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, Tables);
                dtoItem.test = Result;
            }
        }
        return dtoItem;
    }
```

**Update:**
I have updated the code to the below. It just hangs when I run it and only writes 1/4 of the data to the server?  Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
      public static ITargetBlock<T> CreateGuaranteedBroadcastBlock<T>(IEnumerable<ITargetBlock<T>> targets, DataflowBlockOptions options)
    {
        var targetsList = targets.ToList();

        var block = new ActionBlock<T>(
            async item =>
            {
                foreach (var target in targetsList)
                {
                    await target.SendAsync(item);
                }
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                CancellationToken = options.CancellationToken
            });

        block.Completion.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            foreach (var target in targetsList)
            {
                if (task.Exception != null)
                    target.Fault(task.Exception);
                else
                    target.Complete();
            }
        });

        return block;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task< HttpResponseMessage> ReloadItem(string projectQuery)
    {
        try
        {

            var linkCompletion = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                 MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
            };
             var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var dbOptions = new DataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = cts.Token };


            IList<string> projectIds = projectQuery.Split(',').ToList();
            IEnumerable<string> serverList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerList"].Split(',').Cast<string>();

            var iR = new TransformBlock<MemcachedDTO, MemcachedDTO>(
                dto => dto.GetIR(dto), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 });

            List<ActionBlock<MemcachedDTO>> actionList = new List<ActionBlock<MemcachedDTO>>();


            List<MemcachedDTO> dtoList = new List<MemcachedDTO>();

            foreach (string pid in projectIds)
            {
                IList<MemcachedDTO> dtoTemp = new List<MemcachedDTO>();
                dtoTemp = MemcachedDTO.GetItemIdsByProject(pid);
                dtoList.AddRange(dtoTemp);
            }
            foreach (string s in serverList)
            {
                var action = new ActionBlock<MemcachedDTO>(
                async dto => await PostEachServerAsync(dto, s, "setitemcache"));
                actionList.Add(action);
            }
            var bBlock = CreateGuaranteedBroadcastBlock(actionList, dbOptions);

            foreach (MemcachedDTO d in dtoList)
            {
                await iR.SendAsync(d);
            }

            iR.Complete();
            iR.LinkTo(bBlock);
            await Task.WhenAll(actionList.Select(action => action.Completion).ToList());

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { message = projectIds.ToString() + " reload success" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { message = ex.Message.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Related: [BroadcastBlock with Guaranteed Delivery in TPL Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127660/broadcastblock-with-guaranteed-delivery-in-tpl-dataflow)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I have 1000 items in iR but only 998 were written to the servers. Did I loose items by using broadCastBlock?

Yes in the code below you set `BoundedCapacity` to one, if at anytime your `BroadcastBlock` cannot pass along an item it will drop it. Additionally a `BroadcastBlock` will only propagate `Completion` to one `TargetBlock`, do not use `PropagateCompletion=true` here. If you want all blocks to complete you need to handle `Completion` manually. This can be done by setting the `ContinueWith` on the `BroadcastBlock` to pass `Completion` to all of the connected targets.

```
var action = new ActionBlock<MemcachedDTO>(dto => PostEachServerAsync(dto, s, "set"), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3, BoundedCapacity = 1 });
broadcast.LinkTo(action, linkCompletion);
actionList.Add(action);
```

**Option:** Instead of the `BroadcastBlock` use a properly bounded `BufferBlock`. When your downstream blocks are bound to one item they cannot receive additional items until they finish processing what they have. That will allow the `BufferBlock` to offer its items to another, possibly idle, `ActionBlock`.

When you add items into a throttled flow, i.e. a flow with a `BoundedCapacity` less than `Unbounded`. You need to be using the  `SendAsync` method or at least handling the return of `Post`. I'd recommend simply using `SendAsync`:

```
foreach (MemcachedDTO d in dtoList)
{
    await iR.SendAsync(d);
}
```

That will force your method signature to become:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReloadItem(string projectQuery)
```

> 2) Am I doing the await on all actionBlocks correctly?

The previous change will permit you to loose the blocking `Wait` call in favor of a `await Task.WhenAlll`

```
iR.Complete();
actionList.ForEach(x => x.Completion.Wait());

To:

iR.Complete();
await bufferBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(tsk => actionList.ForEach(x => x.Complete());
await Task.WhenAll(actionList.Select(action => action.Completion).ToList());
```

> 3) How do I make the database call async?

I'm going to leave this open because it should be a separate question unrelated to `TPL-Dataflow`, but in short use an `async` Api to access your Db and `async` will naturally grow through your code base. [This should get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374697/how-to-properly-make-asynchronous-parallel-database-calls).

**BufferBlock vs BroadcastBlock**

After re-reading your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338468/tpl-dataflow-how-to-call-action-item-multiple-items) and the answer from @VMAtm. It seems you want each item sent to ***All*** five servers, in that case you will need a `BroadcastBlock`. You would use a `BufferBlock` to distribute the messages relatively evenly to a flexible pool of servers that each could handle a message. None the less, you will still need to take control of propagating completion and faults to all the connected `ActionBlocks` by awaiting the completion of the `BroadcastBlock`.

**To Prevent BroadcastBlock Dropped Messages**

In general you two options, set your `ActionBlocks` to be unbound, which is their default value:

```
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3, BoundedCapacity = Unbounded });
```

**Or** broadcast messages your self from any variety of your own construction. [Here is an example implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082064/alternate-to-dataflow-broadcastblock-with-guaranteed-delivery) from @i3arnon. [And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918800/tpl-dataflow-bounded-capacity-and-waiting-for-completion) from @svick

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response @JSteward.  I have updated my code in the above post and am still having issues... The application does not complete (I removed PropagateCompletion) and only writes 1/4 of the records.  Could you please point me in the right direction?  Thanks

Comment: The first thing that jumps out is: you're not linking your `TransformBlock` to your `BroadcastBlock` until after all data is sent into the flow. What happens when you fix that part?

Comment: Another possibility, `PostEachServerAsync` is not awaited, if it's running `async` then it's being treated as fire and forget and may not complete by the time your flow completes.

Comment: I have updated the code above @JSteward - please see updated code.  I have linked the transform block to the broadcast block and awaited PostEachServerAsync.  Now I am getting a Exception thrown: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in System.Data.dll.  Do you have any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

Comment: I don't actually see any update to your code, but you do have an unbound flow. Meaning that every `MemcachedDTO` is in memory. At this point you need to profile your code and find what's taking up so much memory. You can try throttling your flow to only allow _x_ number of items through at a given time. If you need further help, you'll need [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and can post another question.

Comment: I do see the `await` on `PostEachServerAsync` but an `OutOfMemoryException` likely means your trying to handle too much data all at once. You need to profile your code and find out what's eating up your memory. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be your best bet to get any further help with the exception.